QCrowdSourcedSupplier Class Not Being Generated
I’m working on a Spring Boot project and trying to generate the QCrowdSourcedSupplier class using QueryDSL for a MongoDB entity. However, the class is not being generated despite setting up QueryDSL dependencies.
Error in Console:
error: Annotation processor 'com.querydsl.apt.MongoAnnotationProcessor' not found
Environment:
•   Spring Boot Version: 3.3.6
•   QueryDSL Version: 5.1.0
•   Java Version: 17.0
•   IDE: Intellij utimate

I’ve already tried multiple solutions but still face the same issue.
1.Enabled Annotation Processing:
Verified that annotation processing is enabled in the IDE.
2.Checked QueryDSL Dependencies:
Made sure that the following dependencies are present in my pom.xml
3.Swagger Configuration Adjustments:
Fixed several issues caused by Springfox and ensured Swagger works without breaking other configurations.
4.Added Generated Sources Folder:
Added target/generated-sources/java as a Content Root in the IDE.
5.Adjusted @ApiResponse Usage:
Updated ApiSupplierFiltersAndPageableDoc.java to ensure annotations don’t cause conflicts.
6.Modified CrowdSourcedSupplierApi.java:
Made relevant changes to ensure compatibility with Swagger and QueryDSL.
7.Verified MongoDB Annotation Processor:
Checked the MongoAnnotationProcessor configuration in pom.xml.
